# google app engine sending mail twice

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

I wrote a sample code to send email from google app engine in Python. I'm not able to figure out why is it sending out every mail twice?

**mail.py**:-

```
from google.appengine.api import mail

mail.send_mail(sender="ALPHA <ALPHA@gmail.com>",
        to="BETA <BETA@hotmail.com>",
        subject="test mail",
        body="""

Dear BETA,
How have you been?

Regards,
ALPHA
""")
```

**app.yaml**:-

```
application: MyUniqueAppID
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: .*
script: mail.py
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If that *really* is your app.yaml, then **any** request to your app is going to result in a mail being sent.

If you visit the site with a web-browser, it will first make a request for `/`, then probably also make a request for `/favicon.ico` and potentially other unintended requests. Each resulting in a mail being sent.

You should:

1. Make your `url` route in app.yaml more specific than .*
2. Not just place your code directly in the module scope as you appear to have done for mail.py. Modules can get cached and although this **will** work, it might not work like that forever, so use the [`webbapp`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/overview.html) framework to create a propper application/handler within mail.py